# handleActionWithIdentifier: forLocalNotification: not fired sometimes

Tags: ios9, watchkit, uilocalnotification

There is no pattern to it, but sometimes handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification: is not getting fired when a tap is done on a background action button of a local notification. It happens more often when the action button is tapped on a notification delivered on Watch, but sometimes it happens with notification delivered on iPhone as well.

This is how I came to the conclusion that the method is not fired.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *str = [[defaults objectForKey:@"WatchActionLog"]?[defaults objectForKey:@"WatchActionLog"]:@"" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"**S**%@",[notification.userInfo valueForKeyPath:@"customDictionary.notificationName"]]];
[defaults setObject:str forKey:@"WatchActionLog"];
[defaults synchronize];

// Do something

str = [[defaults objectForKey:@"WatchActionLog"]?[defaults objectForKey:@"WatchActionLog"]:@"" stringByAppendingString:@"**E**"];
[defaults setObject:str forKey:@"WatchActionLog"];
[defaults synchronize];

completionHandler();}
```

Every time the action did not do what it had to do, I have noticed the WatchActionLog was not updated too.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *str = [defaults objectForKey:@"WatchActionLog"];
NSLog(@"Watch action log - %@",str);

// Remaining code follows }
```

Has anyone else seen this problem too. [This](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20553) is the only other mention I have found so far. I am testing on iOS 9 + watchOS 2.

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure out how to get the handleActionWithIdentifier method to fire as well. I'll report back if I figure something out - or i'd love to see if you found a solution!

Comment: Its not that it never fires. Just that sometimes it unpredictably doesn't.

Comment: hmm. I can never get it to fire. I'm trying to verify with print statements (i'm not sure how else to see whether it ever get's called besides break points). This post says he had to move his completion handler until it actually completed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869352/ios-8-push-notification-action-buttons-code-in-handleactionwithidentifier-does

Comment: Don't be so sure that its never getting called. It does get called. You can add the code snippet I gave above as a sure way to know if it gets called or not.

Comment: completionHandler just determines at what point the method returns, not if the method itself is getting called or not.

Comment: I'm new to iOS and just started with Swift. Are you saying your code snippet is the alternative way to see if it gets called because print statements don't work? If i just use break points and print statements and neither of them get called out, it could still be getting called?

**Edit** just saw your explanation. I see... okay. I'll try to convert your snippet into swift